# Printing html page and doing some action using 1 button

Tags: php, html

I have a *Print* button which I want to do 2 actions when clicked:

1. Updating my database.
2. Printing the HTML page.

This is what I've done so far, but it's not working:

```
   <form action="" method="POST">
<body >
  <?php

    $n=$_POST['ID'];
    $a=implode("</br>",$n);

    list($add, $ward) = explode("(!@!)", $a);
    ?> 
    <div id="container">
        <p id="address">
        <?php echo"$address";?>
        </p>
        <p id="ward">
        <?php echo"$ward";?>
        </p>
    </div>
     <input type="submit" name="Print" value="Print" />
     <?php
     if(isset($_POST['Print']))
     {  
     ?><script>javascript:window.print()</script><?php
        mysql_query("UPDATE `source_main` SET `source_status`=3 WHERE `source_id`=1");
    }?>
 <div id="footer">
</div>
</form>
```

After using this print button ,  my database is getting updated, but the print window is showing error(i.e the variables posted from other page are showing errors).

Can anyone please help me print and update at same time with this *Print* button?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: Check any errors in the update statement. make sure it works fine.

Comment: The update query doesn't have any errors @Stasel

Comment: @LillyShk you have an error in update query remove `;` from end of query

Comment: I am sorry if u all dint get my question.I have edited my question,please have a look

Comment: 1) invalid HTML 2) where is the `<input name="ID"...>`? 3) remove `javascript:`

Answer (score 1):

If your page does not have it, add form tags. They are mandatory unless you want to AJAX the data. Also remove the semi-colon from the end of the sql

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" name="Print" value="Print" />
</form>

 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['Print'])) {
   mysql_query("UPDATE `source_main` SET `source_status`=3 WHERE `source_id`=1"); 
   ?><script>window.print();</script>
 <?php } ?>
```

UPDATE: Perhaps you mean this, but I do not want to keep correcting HTML.

```
<?php 
  $n=$_POST["ID"]; 
  $a=implode("</br>",$n); 
  list($add,$ward)=explode("(!@!)", $a); 
?>
<body>
    <div id="headerbg">
        <div id="header-e1"><a align="left" href="escalationReport.php">Back </a>
        </div>
        <div id="header-e3"><a align="right" href="logout.php">Logout </a>
        </div>
         <h1><p>Issue Notice</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <p id="address">
            <?php echo "$address";?>
        </p>
        <p id="ward">
            <?php echo "$ward";?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="Print" value="Print" />
    </form>
    <?php if(isset($_POST[ 'Print'])) { 
       mysql_query( "UPDATE `source_main` SET `source_status`=3 WHERE `source_id`=1"); 
    ?>
    <script>
        window.print();
    </script>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have updated my question, Can u please have a look

Comment: You need form fields to access ID - the P does not get passed to the server

Comment: sql is working fine, its getting updated and the print dialogue box also appears. But the values that I got from the previous page i.e 'ID' is showing undefined

Comment: Are you posting a form from the previous page to this page using a form with method post and a field called ID ?

Comment: Yes I am sending ID value from esc.php to this page

Comment: See my update. you need to make sure your html and php is valid

Comment: Its still giving error as Notice: Undefined index: ID

Comment: That is unrelated to this code and question. It is the previous page that does not pass the ID correctly in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

you have an error in the update query, you have placed `semicolon` inside the query so please remove that so the query will be like this.

Make sure your form method is `POST`

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE `source_main` SET `source_status`=3 WHERE `source_id`=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using input type button inside the form tag. And use post method for form.